# MariaDB convert_tz maketime

Tags: date, mariadb

When I run this query

```
select convert_tz( 
    concat( 
        (`last_mailing` + interval 1 day), ' ', maketime(`email_delivery_hour`,0,0) 
          ),
    'EST','GMT') 
    FROM `member_subscriptions`
```

the date - time stamps returned include fractions of a second, such as

```
2014-07-01 05:00:00.000000
```

I need the date - time to return in the format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS
```

- `last_mailing` is column type datetime
- `email_delivery_hour` is column type int(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MAKETIME](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/maketime/) returns TIME hence *CONCAT* with DATETIME would not work as expected.

Instead one can use [ADDTIME](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/addtime/) instead to get the desired result

Example :

```
CONVERT_TZ(ADDTIME(`last_mailing` + INTERVAL 1 DAY,MAKETIME(`email_delivery_hour`,0,0)),'GMT','EST');
```

Comment: This query is part of a MariaDB view.  I am converting to pgSQL.  The reason I am changing this to begin with is because pgSQL doesn't support datetime(6) (what would be required with how this query was producing before your help.)

Comment: The error I am having now is: Error: column "next_devotion_send_gmt_date" of relation "member_subscriptions_list_1" does not exist

Comment: Or is the real error that the databases this relies on aren't loaded yet?

Comment: Ahh!  i've discovered a capital letter caused this second eror.